# Не работает jquery внутри ballon

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

```
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.907228, 31.260503], {
        balloonContentHeader: "Балун метки",
        balloonContentBody: "<button class='set-moderated'>модерировать</button>",
        balloonContentFooter: "Подвал",
        hintContent: "Хинт метки"
    });

$('.set-moderated').on('click', function() {
    alert('успешно промодерировано');
});
```

создаю метку с балуном, в `balloonContentBody` вписываю html c классом 
`'set-moderated'` для срабатывания события jquery, но оно не срабатывает. 
Знаю, что есть решение через создание своего шаблона. Но есть ли более простое решение? Ведь у меня на сайте используются много виджетов, и они все стандартизированно рендерятся, куда мне нужно,- я их прям туда в `balloonContentBody` и рендерю, и переписывание шаблонов мне как-то не очень нравится.

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день. В момент вызова "on" элемента ".set-moderated" еще нет на странице.
В вашем случае правильным способом будет делегирование события. Не подписаться на клики всех ".set-moderated", а на клики всех ".set-moderated" внутри какого-то другого элемента, который уже существует на момент вызова "on".

Что-то типа

```
$("#map").on( "click", ".set-moderated", function () { ... });
```

Подробнее про делегирование событий в jquery
http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 0):

Очень актуальная для меня тема... пытался определить onClick передавая его через properties  в кастромном шаблоне. ничего ен вышло - функция привелкась к строке при передаче в шаблон. Есть ли возможность связаь функцию с нажатием, не используя поиск по dom и глобальные объекты?

Comment: спасибо ) уже нашел решение такое же здесь же) но вот не знаю теперь как запускать modal bootstrap который тоже рендерится в балун  `code` $(document).on('click', '#AddmanualAddress1325', function (e) {
$("#manualAddress1325").modal();
});`code`

Comment: у меня хорошо сработало, когда я повесил обработчик при создании балуна: ``ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      `тут шаблон`, { 
build : function() { тут вешаю обработчик }
})``